# What's wrong with this short change of base proof?

Tags: logarithms

Okay so I think I have a very trivial and short proof for the change of base rule but I'm worried it might be circular or wrong since I see it nowhere.

**To prove** $$\log_bx = \frac{\log_ax}{\log_ab}$$

Proving that $\log_ax = \log_ab*\log_bx$ will prove the above since it's the result of multiplying both sides by $\log_ab$ and hence the same relationship.

$\log_ab*\log_bx = \log_ab^{\log_bx}$               // Logarithm power rule.

$\log_ab^{\log_bx} = \log_ax$                      // By definition $b^{\log_bx} = x$

Q.E.D. ?

Comment: You could immediately say $\log_a b^{\log_b x} = \log_a x$ by definition, skipping the first step of your proof.

Comment: Your proof is just fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your proof.  I tried to do a quick google search and most of the pages I found were of the very basic "just accept this rule cause I say so", but I was under the impression must explanations would be very similar to yours.

Comment: You can start with $b^{\log_bx}=a^{\log_ax}$ and apply $\log_a$ to both sides but your proof is fine